# Are Bootstrap 3 and Boostrap 4 - alpha versions currently backward compatible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Are Bootstrap 3 and Boostrap 4 - alpha versions currently backward compatible?

I try to substitute Bootstrap 3 by a new alpha version, but the result styles are broken. Am I doing something wrong or it is a common problem?

Comment: Only parts of each major release are backwards compatible. For the most part, if you're upgrading or downgrading your Bootstrap version, it's going to require a rewrite of your pages.

Comment: That is so pity that browsers have not implemented scoped css feature yet :'-(

Comment: Why would Bootstrap 4 be backwards compatible? As far as I know, no major updates have been backwards compatible. It's just not important. And oh how unfortunate that has been.

Comment: Here's a 3 to 4.x migration tool that may help: http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is not backward compatible with Bootstrap 3.
For more information see the official [Guidance on how to upgrade from Bootstrap v3.x to v4.x](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/).