# Update From Bootstrap 3.7 to 5.0.2 in .net mvc producing Error- System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

I uninstalled the basic bootstrap template that comes with .net MVC Application and installed the bootstrap 5.0.2 from NuGetPackage Manager. Now I am Encountering this Problem At the runtime (Build is happening successfully) :

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WebGrease
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteralProperty(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteral(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionList(JSToken terminator)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseMemberExpression(AstNode expression, List`1 newContexts)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseBlock()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseArrowFunction(AstNode parameters)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionList(JSToken terminator)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseMemberExpression(AstNode expression, List`1 newContexts)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseBlock()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseIfStatement()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunctionBody(Block body)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunction(FunctionType functionType, Context fncCtx)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteralProperty(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteral(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseVarDecl(JSToken inToken)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseVariableStatement()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunctionBody(Block body)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunction(FunctionType functionType, Context fncCtx)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpression(Boolean single, JSToken inToken)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionList(JSToken terminator)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseMemberExpression(AstNode expression, List`1 newContexts)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpression(Boolean single, JSToken inToken)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatements(Block block)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.InternalParse()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.Parse(DocumentContext sourceContext)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyJavaScript(String source, CodeSettings codeSettings)
   at System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
   at System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets)
   at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(String[] paths)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in D:\C# Projects\cv\cv\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 39

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in _Layout.cshtml
```

This is my _Layout.cshtml File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Error Happening in the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`

This is the BundleConfig.cs file:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace cv
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap has had a dependency on Popper.js since v4 - you'll need to add that to your bundle or use the bootstrap.bundle.js version.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We replaced the following:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mybundle").Include(
                "~/Scripts/...",
                "~/Scripts/..."));
```

with:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/mybundle").Include(
                "~/Scripts/...",
                "~/Scripts/..."));
```

Comment: using Bundle instead of ScriptBundle prevents js minification

Comment: @ashubuntu What is the alternative?

Comment: You can use the bootstrap.bundle.min.js which is already minified.

Comment: Any explantation why does this error happen?

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap versions 3, 4 and 5 are completely different. Bootstrap has no backwards compatibility. The class names have all changed from version 3.

**Another Similar Question**
[Are Bootstrap 3 and Boostrap 4 - alpha versions currently backward compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140188/are-bootstrap-3-and-boostrap-4-alpha-versions-currently-backward-compatible)

According to Tim Corey you can upgrade with no compatability issues to any version inside of a larger version of Bootstrap. Each new major version of Bootstrap is a complete overhaul.

**Tim Corey explaining**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ck9LIBxO14

For those who don't want to watch the full video it is explained at 09:50