# Installing Bootstrap 5 in ASP.NET MVC web app on .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5, popper

I am trying to update an ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.8 to use Bootstrap 5.1.

I followed this steps:

1. Generate an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) application.
2. Update Bootstrap using NuGet Package Manager from version 3.4.1 to version 5.1.3
3. Installed popperjs/core@2.11.2 using Add/Client-Side Library / jsdelivr
4. Create a ScriptBundle to  popperjs/core@2.11.2
5. Change _Layout.cshtml

`BundleConfig` class:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        .....

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/popperCore").Include(
                    "~/lib/popperjs/core/dist/cjs/popper.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        ......
    }
}
```

**OLD** `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**NEW** `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - DosMy ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/popperCore")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

with bundles, I get this error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` cdn, it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ....
</head>
<body>
    ....

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

If I used popper/core and bootstrap.min.js cdn it does NOT work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ....
</head>
<body>
    ....

       
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why it is not working with bundles? And how to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251763/update-from-bootstrap-3-7-to-5-0-2-in-net-mvc-producing-error-system-nullrefer

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem of updating Bootstrap 5 with MVC 5
you have to hide

```js
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

and add

```js
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

in layout

Answer (score 0):

Can you try change:

BundleConfig class:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",                      
                      "..."));
```

I try it and done with Bootstrap 5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).